# Can I use lan wire color combination like 1=Light Orange , 2=Orange, 3=Light Blue, 4 and 5 null and 6=Blue?

Tags: networking, lan

Can I use lan wire color combination like 1=Light Orange , 2=Orange, 3=Light Blue, 4 and 5 null and 6=Blue intsted of 1=Light Orange , 2=Orange, 3=Light Green, 4 and 5 null and 6=Green in Lan wire connection? Would that work?

[here is my lan pin connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v2QG.jpg)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use it data-flow is important, more over you can see the ISP crimping will be same as you said.just try to crimp the color pattern and check it once hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you added your desired colors to RJ45 you need to crimp the same on opposite side if you use lan wire color combination like 1=Light Orange , 2=Orange, 3=Light Blue, 4 and 5 null and 6=Blue on one end the other end should be the same as 1=Light Orange , 2=Orange, 3=Light Blue, 4 and 5 null and 6=Blue as I tried the same it worked for me try it it work for you as well